# How discover the element with the max font-size

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I'm trying to answer the call of a function based on comparison of THIS element (keyword) font-size with font-sizes of other elements:

This is inside a prototype:

The self.settings.same is an array with the other elements.

```
self.settings.same.forEach(function (item) {
  var me    = parseInt(self.element.css('fontSize').substring(-1, 2), 10);
  var other = parseInt(item.css('fontSize').substring(-1, 2), 10);

  if (other > me) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
});
```

I want return false if the others elements have the font-size bigger then the current element, but this is not working because it makes the loop only once, so the comparison occurs only once.

Comment: this question is very unclear. in what context does this piece of code exists? how does it even called? that is `item`? do you test a specific element in relation to other specific set of elements or all the elements on the page? because that would be pretty slow..

Comment: The [*forEach*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18) method returns *undefined*, regardless of the value that the callback returns. A more appropriate method is [*every*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.16).

Answer (score 0):

If you can return false only when all `others` elements are bigger than `me`, then this should work.

```
self.settings.same.forEach(function (item) {
  var me    = parseInt(self.element.css('fontSize').substring(-1, 2), 10);
  var other = parseInt(item.css('fontSize').substring(-1, 2), 10);

  if (other < me) {
    return true;
  }

});
return false;
```